# Why won't this cumulative sum in MySQL work?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to get a cumulative sum of orders by hour between two dates:

```
SELECT tDate, nHour, COUNT(tIPN) AS num, (@csum := @csum + COUNT(tIPN)) as sum

FROM TBL_DATES
JOIN TBL_HOURS 
LEFT JOIN VIEW_PAYPAL ON DATE(tIPN) = tDate AND HOUR(tIPN) = nHour
JOIN (SELECT @csum := 0) r

WHERE tDate BETWEEN '2018-08-05' AND '2018-08-17'

GROUP BY tDate, nHour

ORDER BY tDate, nHour;
```

But I get this result:

```
tDate       nHour num sum
2018-08-05  0     2   2
2018-08-05  1     1   1
2018-08-05  2     0   0
2018-08-05  3     0   0
2018-08-05  4     0   0
2018-08-05  5     0   0
2018-08-05  6     2   2
2018-08-05  7     4   4
2018-08-05  8     5   5
2018-08-05  9     5   5
2018-08-05  10    5   5
2018-08-05  11    7   7
2018-08-05  12    11  11
```

What am I doing wrong?  I tried using a separate SET statement instead, it made no difference.

Comment: What are you doing wrong? This: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
SET @csum := 0;

SELECT tDate, nHour, COUNT(tIPN) AS num, (@csum := @csum + COUNT(tIPN)) as cumulative_sum

FROM TBL_DATES
JOIN TBL_HOURS 
LEFT JOIN VIEW_PAYPAL ON DATE(tIPN) = tDate AND HOUR(tIPN) = nHour

WHERE tDate BETWEEN '2018-08-05' AND '2018-08-17'

GROUP BY tDate, nHour

ORDER BY tDate, nHour;
```

First of all, you should initialize the `@csum` variable with `SET`.

Secondly, it's not the best idea to have a column alias named `sum`, because it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but that gives the exact same result I'm afraid.

Comment: SQLfiddle example might help a lot here.